# Light content of uistatusbar affects the colour of uinavigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

light content of uistatusbarstyle overlapped on navigationbart like this, anyone plz help on this this really giving head ache
 in login viewcontroller

```
                    HomeViewController *Home = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
                        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Home];
                        [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

in home viewcontroller

```
UINavigationBar *bar= [UINavigationBar appearance];
bar.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: **overlapped on navigationbart like this**, How?

Comment: sorry i've added the image, but am not allowed to add image

Comment: actually because of the light content of the uistatusbar, my navigation bar is overlapped by white colour, can u get me?

Comment: Show me, how you are deal with the UINavigationBar Color

Comment: sorry am new to stack overflow, how i can message you in this?